# C project using pointers to send arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

In this program I have to create a system of pointers that will, after reading in only 80 characters of a larger input, supply a `pointer-to-pointer-to-character` operation. The result is then sent to a function determining the number of words in the total input and the average amount of letters they contain. My problem is that I cannot dont't know how to create the pointer system without generating a `exc_bad_access` warning. Additionally I cannot find a combination of malloc and free that is suiting my needs. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
inputPtr = (char*)malloc(81 * sizeof(char));

while (fgets(wordy, 81, stdin) != NULL) {
    numChar = strlen(wordy);

    inputPtr = wordy;
    for (i = 0; i < groupRange; ++i) {
        sentPtr[i] = &inputPtr;
    }
    if (numChar == 80) {
        groupRange++;
    }
    free(inputPtr);
    printwords(*sentPtr, numChar);
}
```

Comment: You seem to try to do string copying here: `inputPtr = wordy;`, I guess. In C, strings don't work like that. You might want to take a few steps back and learn about C strings, before creating "pointer systems", whatever you mean by that. But one thing you should think about is, why do you `malloc` once, but then `free` in a loop?

Comment: You leaked the memory you allocated for `inputPtr` on your very first iteration. And we have no idea what `wordy` is. Wild guess: this isn't your *real* code?

Comment: Stop "trying to find a combination of malloc and free that will relieve me of this" because guessing won't work. Instead try to figure it out logically. If you can't figure it out yet then you might need to learn more about pointers, strings or `malloc`, that's fine.

Comment: What is `wordy`, and what is the prototype for `printwords()`?

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a close look at these three lines from your code:

```
inputPtr = (char*)malloc(81 * sizeof(char));
...
inputPtr = wordy;
...
free(inputPtr);
```

The first allocates memory, and assign the pointer to that memory to the variable `inputPtr`.

The second line *reassigns* `inputPtr` so it no longer points to the memory you have allocated. You will lose that memory and have a *memory leak*.

Finally the last line, where you attempt to free what `inputPtr` is pointing to, and exactly what it is pointing to I don't know but it probably isn't memory you have allocated with `malloc`. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Exactly how to solve your problem I'm not sure about, but a good start would be to not allocate memory dynamically, and then of course not call `free`.